# Codenameone does not scan barcode

Tags: codenameone, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have to scan a barcode after a button press in an app mobile developed with Codenameone.

I've added the library `cn1-codescan.cn1lib` from https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan and this is the code:

```
CodeScanner.getInstance().scanBarCode(new ScanResult()
{
    public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes)
    {
        System.out.println(contents);
        /*TextContent*/ tc.text(contents);
        tc.revalidate();
        System.out.println("scannato");
    }

    public void scanCanceled()
    {
        System.out.println("cancelled");
    }

    public void scanError(int errorCode, String message)
    {
        System.out.println("err " + message);
    }
});
```

At the button press, in the simulation nothing appens (and it's fine), in the Android app it opens a second app to scan the barcode.

The problem is that this second app doesn't actually scan the code. It remains in "camera mode" but don't switch back to my app.

How can I switch back to my app with the barcode read?

(If I use this second app searately, opened by itself, it normally works and read the barcode)

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of barcode scanning in Android is flaky and often dependent on the app handling the intent which is generally bad. That's just Android. In this case it's possible that the app just couldn't read the barcode and just stays there waiting. Most apps show a cancel button too.

As an alternative you can try the little monkey cn1lib which includes a native barcode scanner directly into your app on Android. It's an extension to the existing cn1lib so you would use both together. You can get it [here](https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner).